# Character encoding in MySQL. Letters as primary key

Tags: mysql, unicode, encoding

Trying to create table where letters *Char(1)* are primary keys.
Receiving 'duplicate key' error when trying to insert both i and ї оr г and ґ (ukrainian alphabet).

I've tried:

```
utf8_general_ci (allows г + ґ, but not i + ї)
utf8_unicode_ci (does not allow г + ґ)
utf8mb4_general_ci (does not allow i + ї)
utf8mb4_unicode_ci (does not allow г + ґ)
```

I need unicode, as it should support different languages. That's why cp1251_ukrainian_ci is not an option (haven't tested it).

**UPDATE:**

```
utf8mb4_bin (allowed і, ї, г, ґ)
```

This encoding, however, doesn't sort letters well. So, when SELECT I have to use

```
ORDER BY letter COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci ASC
```

But still, it's not sorting DESC

Comment: You will indeed have to use a `bin` collation, which by definition treats everything as unique (all other collations, well, *collate* certain characters together). You can then indeed override that collation for individual queries if you need certain sorting/collation behaviour. What exactly do you mean that this usage won't sort DESC?

Comment: @deceze Tried to execute SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY col COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DESC. But it's showing me ASC order.

Comment: No, I think it is saying that `'г' = 'ґ`.  If there is nothing else to differentiate the lines, then it might be equivalent to ASC or DESC.

Comment: The latest implemented Unicode standard is 5.20, hence the name of that collation.  Coming soon is MySQL 8.0, which includes Unicode 9.0 collation.

Comment: @RickJames will be waiting :) Talking about utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci in fact, in my case, it doesn't sort DESC at all. No matter ASC or DESC it is showing me 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',... (in Ukrainian characters). I hope 9.0 will be better.

Comment: Please provide the Ukrainian alphabet; I'll do some testing.

Comment: INSERT INTO letter (letter) VALUES ('а'), ('б'), ('в'), ('г'), ('ґ'), ('д'), ('е'), ('є'), ('ж'), ('з'), ('и'), ('і'), ('ї'), ('й'), ('к'), ('л'), ('м'), ('н'), ('о'), ('п'), ('р'), ('с'), ('т'), ('у'), ('ф'), ('х'), ('ц'), ('ч'), ('ш'), ('щ'), ('ь'), ('ю'), ('я')